# Issue with results ordering: Query importrange Vs ArrayFormula(query(TO_TEXT(importrange)

Tags: google-sheets, sql-order-by, array-formulas, importrange

I would like to understand how I can make sure that the following two functions produce the same results in terms of ordering.

So, 1st function:

```
=query(importrange("URL";"'A sheet'!A3:AH");"Select Col33, Col25 where Col17='Yes' AND Col18<>'Yes' order by Col33";1)
```

2nd function:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(TO_TEXT(importrange("URL";"'A sheet'!A3:AH"));"select Col33, Col25 where Col17='Yes' AND Col18<>'Yes' order by Col33";1))
```

Unfortunately, the second function provide results in a different order compared to the first. How can I fix it? I thought that ordering by the same column would solve it. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Works the same on this end. Please share a test sheet with expected results.

Comment: depends on your queried set. the 2nd one will order numbers as 1,11,2 while 1st one will order it 1,2,11. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result